# Visual Basic setting a global variable making my code DRY

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

How do I optimize my code making it DRY approach. I want to make my variable to be on public/general so i can re-use it

```
Public Class BasicForm

Dim Product1, Product2, Product3, As Integer
Dim firstName, lastName As String

Private Sub btn_getValue_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_getValue.Click


    'Set variables'
    Product1 = Val(tx_productfield1.Text)
    Product2 = Val(tx_productfield2.Text)
    Product3 = Val(tx_productfield3.Text)


    'Calculate'
    tx_totalValue.Text = Product1 + Product2 + Product3


End Sub End Class
```

I want to move the variables (product1,product2) to somewhere else that I can set it one time and easily access it with other control. What I did before is I alway set the variables to every control.

Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm getting your question, but you know your variables are instance variables, because you're working in a class, right?

Your "product" variables should be private instances, or public properties. If you use the private instances, give a way to access those variables, say Getter methods. Otherwise the "Property" is just fine.

```
Public Class BasicForm

    Public Function getProduct1() As Integer
        return Product1
    End Function

    '... other getters here


    Private Product1 As Integer
    Private Product2 As Integer
    Private Product3 As Integer
End Class
```